# Curly Braces in \newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want to draw a lot of different diagrams, but they all have common features. I want to have parameters for colour, shape, size, in a separate place so that I can fiddle with them at the end, and all the diagrams will change.

As far as I can tell the only way to define "variables" for *multiple* Tikz pictures is to use \newcommand.

My problem now is that if I want to set a colour like `{rgb:blue,1;white,2}`, it throws errors: "! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).", "Missing number, treated as zero.", etc.

More specifically: If I have

```
\filldraw[fill={rgb:red,1;white,2}]  (0,0) circle (0.5cm) node {$Z$};
```

it works fine, but:

```
\newcommand\zcolour{{rgb:red,1;white,2}}
...
\filldraw[fill=\zcolour]  (0,0) circle (0.5cm) node {$Z$};
```

throws the errors. It's not a colour thing, since

```
\newcommand\zcolour{white}
...
\filldraw[fill=\zcolour]  (0,0) circle (0.5cm) node {$Z$};
```

works fine. So I think it's the curly braces.

Hence: Do I need to do anything special to fix the curly braces, or is there a better way to define variables for multiple Tikz pictures?

Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\zcolour{{rgb:red,1;white,2}}
\newcommand\whitecolour{white}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw[fill=\zcolour]  (0,0) circle (0.5cm) node {$Z$};%doesn't work
    \filldraw[fill=\whitecolour]  (0,0) circle (0.5cm) node {$Z$};%works
    \filldraw[fill={rgb:red,1;white,2}]  (0,0) circle (0.5cm) node {$Z$};%works
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

In the mean time you could try `\filldraw[fill={\zcolour}]`.  However, the better way to do this is to use `\tikzset` to define your own styles: `\tikzset{MyFill  Style/.style={fill={rgb:red,1;white,2}}}`.

Comment: Just use `\definecolor{zcolour}{RGB}{NUMBER1,NUMBER2,NUMBER3}` and than (in the `tikzpicture`) `\fill[zcolour]`…

Comment: Or you can do it as `\newcommand\zfill{fill={rgb:red,1;white,2}}` with usage as `\filldraw\expandafter[\zfill]`

Comment: Those are good ideas that solve the immediate problem, though if I need another command with braces, I'll still have a problem. They also inspired another solution: Create a `\makestyles` macro with a series of `\tikzstyle` commands, and use those styles. Basically a macro to construct more macros.

Answer (score 3):

This is what `.styles` are used for. Change the `style` and the figure changes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    mystyle1/.style={
        fill=red,
        draw=blue,
        line width=1mm,
        text=green
        },
    mystyle2/.style={
        fill=blue!30,
        dashed,
        },
    mystyle3/.style={
        fill=none,
        draw=red,
        line width=1mm,
        densely dashed
        },
}       

%\newcommand\zcolour{{rgb:red,1;white,2}}
%\newcommand\whitecolour{white}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \filldraw[mystyle1]  (0,0) circle (0.5cm) node {$Z$};%doesn't work
    \filldraw[mystyle2]  (1.5,0) circle (0.5cm) node {$Z$};%works
    \filldraw[mystyle3]  (3,0) circle (0.5cm) node {$Z$};%works
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]